# public class Extra<BASE> extends BASE

Tags: java, generics

Is there a way to inherit from a baseclass by using the generic type paramater?

```
public class Extra<BASE> extends BASE
```

So that Extra is the new class having all the methods of BASE, like

```
Extra<MyType>
```

Greetings

edit***************

That is disappointing. I'm moving a project from C++ to JAVA.
In C++ this is possible, sadly I used this a lot in this project.

Is there another way to achieve that:

A class has its own userdata-class. It needs the members of its userdata linked with a special functionality, that is given by an other class. The other class is extending the first userdata-class. I don't want to have the userdata as a data member in the new class,
but really as a part of it.

Like:

userdata-class:

String name;

special-functionality-class: a generic TreeKnot,

The new class then should be a TreeKnot combined with the userdata-class.

What way could I go ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible you can create something like this

```
public class Extra extends Base<Base>
```

But what do you want it is not possible at all!!!!

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. Type templating and inheritance are two completely different concepts.

Comment: Ok. Now, I think my approach isn't a good design at all. I changed the code.In the end, this kind of inheritance wasn't necessary. Thank a lot.